# deleted script keeps running

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a google script that should have sent me an email, instead it is now sending me emails continiously.

There was an infinite loop in the script and I could not stop it.
I have tried to delete the script, this did not work.
I have tried to delete the spreadsheed containing the script, this did not work.

Can anyone help?
Is there a way to view running scripts somewhere? (and stop them)

kind regards,

Comment: When a spreadsheet or other document is deleted, it is moved to the trash. Do you have the trash empty now?

Comment: Yes I cleared the trash also. After that I still received some emails but it eventually stopped. I think I have received 1500 emails or something

Comment: Deleting a file will not remove it from memory, so if it was already running, then deleting it would only prevent it from being loaded into memory again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How was your script invoked - through the script editor or through a trigger ? In either case, the script will time out after about 5 minutes. If it was run through a trigger, then deleting the trigger should stop the mails from coming

Comment: I think it has stopped now, I did not receive any mails since I sent this message.

I started the script by pressing "run" in the script manager, I had a do while loop but I somehow forgot to make sure the ending condition was met...

In the future, how can I prevent this?

Comment: If you run it from the script editor, the script will eventually stop after 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

The script eventually stopped after sending me 1500 emails.
I think that is a daily limit of some kind for my business.

Lessons I have learnt from this are: always check your loops and never ever use your own e-mailadres =)