# I accidentally sent myself 175 emails, which have been coming for two days now even though the script was aborted. How do I make them stop

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a mistake in my script so that instead of sending an email to myself once it is sending it hundreds of times. I ran into my quota yesterday, but once 24 hours had passed the emails are starting up again. I've already stopped the script, and I even de-authorized it from having access to the email address it's sending them from. How do I cancel all of the emails which seem to be queued up?

This is the faulty script. There were 175 rows in my spreadsheet, which sends me an email for each row when a certain condition is met. I think I've already fixed the script, I just don't know how to stop the emails that keep coming even though the script itself was aborted.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var emailData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Subjects").getDataRange().getValues();
  var emailSubject = "";
  var headerRow = emailData.shift(); //Remove the header row
  emailData.forEach(function (row) {
     var email = emailData[1];
     var  emailBody = emailData[3];
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, emailSubject, emailBody);
  });
}
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12180981/1595451)

Comment: Nothing, pretty much. Happens, but if the script has completed running already (judging by you asking after waiting a day, it has), the emails are scheduled by Google to be sent. At this point, there is nothing you can do to stop it, wait it out. Unless you have a paid account, you won't be able to contact support directly either. If the emails bother you - set up a filter that moves them to trash as soon as they come in.